# How to count the occurrences of specified character sequences while editing a textarea?

Tags: javascript, regex, event-handling, match, dry

I'm looking for a way to automatically count the specified words in the textarea without having to click a button to do so, and in that case, auto update it if there are changes..

Here's my chaotic code so far:

```js
function findWord1() {
  var outputDiv = $('#opening-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "[";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){ }\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a>');
}

function findWord2() {
  var outputDiv = $('#closing-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "]";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord3() {
  var outputDiv = $('#opening-added-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "[A>";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord4() {
  var outputDiv = $('#closing-added-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "lt;A]";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord5() {
  var outputDiv = $('#opening-deleted-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "[D>";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord6() {
  var outputDiv = $('#closing-deleted-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "lt;D]";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="findWord1();findWord2();findWord3();findWord4();findWord5();findWord6();">Count</button>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Items</th>
        <th scope="col">Count</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>[A&gt;</td>
        <td><a id="opening-added-bracket"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&lt;A]</td>
        <td><a id="closing-added-bracket"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[D&gt;</td>
        <td><a id="opening-deleted-bracket"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&lt;D]</td>
        <td><a id="closing-deleted-bracket"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>[</td>
        <td><a id="opening-bracket"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>]</td>
        <td><a id="closing-bracket"></a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<textarea id="textarea3" rows="5">
[A>
lt;A]
[D>
lt;D]
</textarea>
```

Also if possible, I'd like to retain the "Count" button so I can still manually do it in case the other parts of the code fails..

Apologies if my code looks so bad, but thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: There's a ton of repetition up there. You should probably make one reusable function and pass in your string as an argument, or loop over an array of them. Also, you don't need separate script elements for every function.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it is one of my plans to combine them all under one function, I just haven't figured out yet how I'd do it..

Comment: The `wordMatch` values  of `findWord4` and of `findWord6` need to be fixed as well as the textarea's corresponding values ... `&lt;A]`/`&lt;D]` instead of the current `lt;A]`/`lt;D]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to call all your others. This is a step toward simplifying your code. Then, create an event listener for the textarea's `input` event with the new function as its callback.

This question is essentially a duplicate of many other questions involving events. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events for some good information, and search for more answers here if you have further questions.

```js
function findAllWords() {
  findWord1();
  findWord2();
  findWord3();
  findWord4();
  findWord5();
  findWord6();
}

document.getElementById('textarea3').addEventListener('input', findAllWords);

function findWord1() {
  var outputDiv = $('#opening-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "[";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){ }\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a>');
}

function findWord2() {
  var outputDiv = $('#closing-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "]";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord3() {
  var outputDiv = $('#opening-added-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "[A>";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord4() {
  var outputDiv = $('#closing-added-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "lt;A]";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord5() {
  var outputDiv = $('#opening-deleted-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "[D>";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}

function findWord6() {
  var outputDiv = $('#closing-deleted-bracket');
  var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();
  var wordMatch = "lt;D]";

  outputDiv.empty();

  var m = searchText.match(new RegExp(wordMatch.toString().replace(/(?=[.\\+*?[^\]$(){}\|])/g, "\\"), "ig"));
  outputDiv.append('<a>' + (m ? m.length : 0) + '</a');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Items</th>
      <th scope="col">Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>[A&gt;</td>
      <td>
        <a id="opening-added-bracket"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&lt;A]</td>
      <td>
        <a id="closing-added-bracket"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>[D&gt;</td>
      <td>
        <a id="opening-deleted-bracket"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&lt;D]</td>
      <td>
        <a id="closing-deleted-bracket"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>[</td>
      <td>
        <a id="opening-bracket"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>]</td>
      <td>
        <a id="closing-bracket"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<textarea id="textarea3" rows="5">
[A>
lt;A]
[D>
lt;D]
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my query. This solution is exactly what I need right now. Just one question as I haven't really tried it yet, I assume it's still possible to use the main function `findAllWords()` to create a button that can manually count the words? (Need it cause a script I have programmatically updates the text and I assume it won't update the count after changing the text).

Comment: Sure, but use an event listener for the button as well. Keep your JavaScript out of your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Use `keyup` Simply do this way

```js
function countWordFunc() { 

  let myText = document.getElementById("myText").value;

  let wordsArr = myText.trim().split(" ")
  let countWords = wordsArr.filter(word => word !== "").length
  
  let counter = document.getElementById("counter");
  counter.innerHTML = `Total Words: ${countWords}`;

}
```

```html
<textarea onkeyup="countWordFunc()" id="myText">Hello, World</textarea>

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: _"... automatically count the **specified** words ..."_

Comment: @GMKHussain ... please consider removing this answer since it totally misses the entire problem and fails for any of the OP's requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are following issues with the OP's code ...

- code based on specific *element `id`s* can never be converted into something generic enough in terms of re-usable code.
- counting single brackets is hazardous especially since they are part of other to be matched character sequences (which the OP refers to as words).

Thus, one might consider a configurable and generic as possible, poor-mans, component-like approach similar to the next provided example code, where ...

- one e.g. can configure the to be matched items via regex patterns.
- one furthermore can configure the component's UI/UX behavior like auto-count.
- every configuration is based on [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and its [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) counterpart.
- due to the above 3rd bullet-point a component is agnostic to it's markup as long as the necessary `data-*` attributes are getting provided correctly.

The approach also could be summarized like with one of my comments ...

> *"Initialize a component like structure by reading and computing the config settings, and upon the latter register the count handler with the correct events. The count handler itself then is a straightforward regex based pattern matching (which also works correctly unlike all the other solutions) and count rendering task. Element IDs are not needed, markup is freely selectable, configurations are applied via markup and data attributes. One does not need to touch JS code in order to introduce more to be matched items/words."*

```js
function displayItemCount(itemRoot, target) {
  const elmPattern =
    target && itemRoot?.querySelector('[data-reg-pattern]');

  const elmCount =
    elmPattern && itemRoot?.querySelector('[data-match-count]');

  const regXItem =
    elmCount && RegExp(elmPattern.dataset.regPattern, 'g');

  if (regXItem) {
    elmCount.textContent = (target.value.match(regXItem) ?? []).length;
  }
}
function displayItemCountsOfBoundComponentData() {
  const { rootNode, countsTarget } = this;

  rootNode
    .querySelectorAll('[data-item-match]')
    .forEach(itemRoot =>

      displayItemCount(itemRoot, countsTarget)
    );
}

function initializeItemCountsComponent(rootNode) {
  const { dataset } = rootNode;
  let {
    countsTargetSelector = '',
    triggerCountsSelector = '',
    autoCount = false,
  } = dataset;
  
  countsTargetSelector = countsTargetSelector.trim();
  triggerCountsSelector = triggerCountsSelector.trim();

  const countsTarget = (
    rootNode.querySelector(countsTargetSelector || null) ||
    document.querySelector(countsTargetSelector || null)
  );
  if (countsTarget) {

    let countsTriggers = rootNode
      .querySelectorAll(triggerCountsSelector || null);

    if (countsTriggers.length === 0) {
      countsTriggers = document
        .querySelectorAll(triggerCountsSelector || null);
    }
    const isAutoCount = (
      (countsTriggers.length === 0) || (

        (autoCount !== false) && (

          (autoCount.trim() === '') ||
          (autoCount.trim().toLowerCase() === 'true')
        )
      )
    );
    const displayItemCounts =
      displayItemCountsOfBoundComponentData.bind({
        rootNode,
        countsTarget,
      });

    countsTriggers.forEach(elmNode =>
      elmNode
        .addEventListener('click', displayItemCounts)
    );
    if (isAutoCount) {

      countsTarget
        .addEventListener('input', displayItemCounts);

      // trigger component's initial item counts.
      displayItemCounts();
    }
  }
}

function main() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('[data-item-counts]')
    .forEach(initializeItemCountsComponent);
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
article { position: relative; display: inline-block; margin: 0 20px 0 0; }
[data-item-counts] { float: left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; }
textarea { margin: 0; }
button { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 175px; }
```

```html
<article>
  <table
    data-item-counts
    data-counts-target-selector="#textarea3"
    data-trigger-counts-selector="#count-textarea3-items"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Items</th>
        <th scope="col">Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="\[A>" title="Opening Added Bracket">[A&gt;</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="<A]" title="Closing Added Bracket">&lt;A]</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="\[D>" title="Opening Deleted Bracket">[D&gt;</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="<D]" title="Closing Deleted Bracket">&lt;D]</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="\[(?!A|D)" title="Opening Bracket">[</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="(?<!<A|D)]" title="Closing Bracket">]</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <textarea
    id="textarea3"
    cols="16"
    rows="12">
[A&gt;&lt;A][D&gt;&lt;D][[]][]&lt;A][D&gt;

[A&gt;&lt;A][D&gt;&lt;D][[]][]&lt;A][D&gt;

... explicitly triggered count.</textarea>

  <button id="count-textarea3-items">Count Items</button>
</article>

<article>
  <table
    data-item-counts
    data-counts-target-selector="#textarea54"
    data-auto-count
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Items</th>
        <th scope="col">Count</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="\[A>" title="Opening Added Bracket">[A&gt;</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="<A]" title="Closing Added Bracket">&lt;A]</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="\[D>" title="Opening Deleted Bracket">[D&gt;</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="<D]" title="Closing Deleted Bracket">&lt;D]</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="\[(?!A|D)" title="Opening Bracket">[</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-item-match>
        <td data-reg-pattern="(?<!<A|D)]" title="Closing Bracket">]</td>
        <td data-match-count>.?.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <textarea
    id="textarea54"
    cols="16"
    rows="12"
  >[[]][]&lt;A][D&gt;[A&gt;&lt;A][D&gt;&lt;D]

... auto-count while editing.</textarea>

</article>
```

Comment: This question is very simple and does not deserve these complications

Comment: @YounesBennour ... There is nothing complicated about the above approach. Initialize a component like structure by reading and computing the config settings, and upon the latter register the count handler with the correct events. The count handler itself then is a straightforward regex based pattern matching (which also works correctly unlike all the other solutions) and count rendering task. Element IDs are not needed, markup is freely selectable, configurations are applied via markup and data attributes. One does not need to touch JS code in order to introduce more to be matched items/words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, combined functions into one:

```js
    let textarea = $('#textarea3');
textarea.on('keyup', _ => counting());
function counting() {
    var searchText = $('#textarea3').val();

    let words = [];
    words['[A>'] = '#opening-added-bracket';
    words['<A]'] = '#closing-added-bracket';
    words['[D>'] = '#opening-deleted-bracket';
    words['<D]'] = '#closing-deleted-bracket';
    words['['] = '#opening-bracket';
    words[']'] = '#closing-bracket';

    for (const word in words) {
        var outputDiv = $(words[word]);
        outputDiv.empty();
        let count = searchText.split(word).length - 1;
        searchText = searchText.replaceAll(word,'');
        outputDiv.append('<a>' + count + '</a>');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="counting();">Count</button>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Items</th>
            <th scope="col">Count</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>[A&gt;</td>
            <td><a id="opening-added-bracket"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&lt;A]</td>
            <td><a id="closing-added-bracket"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[D&gt;</td>
            <td><a id="opening-deleted-bracket"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&lt;D]</td>
            <td><a id="closing-deleted-bracket"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>[</td>
            <td><a id="opening-bracket"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>]</td>
            <td><a id="closing-bracket"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<textarea id="textarea3" rows="5">
[A>
<A]
[D>
<D]
</textarea>
```

Comment: The above implementation abuses the `words` array as kind of an object based map. One might consider changing it accordingly e.g. `let words = {};`

Comment: @ixcode ... even worse `<A]` and `<D]` are not at all getting counted. Instead the  `]` count gets wrongly updated ... and the same applies for `[A>` and  `[D>` which both contribute wrongly to the `[` count ... which actually renders the entire approach useless.